# how to \multicolumn in booktabs?

Tags: tables, booktabs

Following is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Case-studies}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllll}
\toprule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{Full}  \\

\cmidrule(r){4-5}
\cmidrule(r){6-7}
\cmidrule(r){8-9}
\cmidrule(r){10-11}

Name & Name & Name & Name & Name. & Name & Name. & Name & Name. & Name & Name. \\
\midrule
John & Doe & $7.5$ \\
Richard & Miles & $2$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{case-studies}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The output is : 
[image]

I want to label "Full" above other columns also. How to do that?
And how to change the spacing between two columns?

Comment: I have problems understanding your question. `Full` is centered above the first 8 columns. There are 11 columns all in all, so `\multicolumn{11}{c}{Full}` will center `Full` above all columns. The space between columns is adjusted with `\tabcolsep`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are probably looking for the following layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Case-studies}
  \begin{tabular}{*{11}{l}}
    \toprule
    & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Full} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Full} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Full} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Full} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
    \cmidrule(lr){10-11}
    Name & Name & Name & Name & Name. & Name & Name. & Name & Name. & Name & Name. \\
    \midrule
    John & Doe & $7.5$ \\
    Richard & Miles & $2$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \label{case-studies}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note that the table caption is not properly aligned since the `tabular` structure is too wide. If need be, you can adjust the column separation which provides a tighter view and possibly make the table fit within the page boundary.

The default of `\tabcolsep` is `6pt`. Anything smaller will shrink the `tabular` horizontally. Using something like `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}`. You could also consider increasing the text block margin using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).