# Using multicolumn with booktabs

Tags: tables, multicolumn, booktabs

[image]

I am trying to make a table outlined by the codes below, but I am not able to use the multicolumn command. I need the header 'Share' over the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th column of Men, Women and pooled respectively. And the header 'Avg hourly wage' over the 5th, 6th, 7th column of Men, Women and pooled respectively. 
The code is attached below.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    \begin{document}
    \documentclass[10.5pt,a4]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=0.5in,a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{capt-of}

     %dashed line
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{arydshln}
    \setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
    \setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}

    %Widows & Orphans & Penalties

    \widowpenalty500
    \clubpenalty500
    \clubpenalty=9996
    \exhyphenpenalty=50 %for line-breaking at an explicit hyphen
   \brokenpenalty=4991
   \predisplaypenalty=10000
   \postdisplaypenalty=1549
   \displaywidowpenalty=1602
   \floatingpenalty = 20000


   \begin{table*}[] \centering
   %\ra{1.3}
    \begin{small}
   \begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrrrr@{}}\toprule
   \textbf{Dependent Variables} & & \textbf{Share(\%)} & & \textbf{Avg hourly wage} & & & \textbf{Avg differential} \\ \hline
   & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled} & \textbf{  Men  } & 
   \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled} \\ \hdashline
   \\
   \textbf{PANEL A: 2011-2012}\ \\ \midrule
   \\
   Panel A.1: Sector (Urban or Rural)\ \\ \hdashline
   Rural  & 51.5 & 54 & 52 & 28.54 & 18.83 & 26.92 & 51.5 \\ \hdashline
   Urban & 48.4 & 46 & 48 & 45.19 & 41.86 & 45 & 7.8 \\ \hdashline
  \\
   Panel A.2: Sector (Public or Private) \\ \hdashline
   Public & 18.6 & 27.7 & 20 & 75.55 & 55.44 & 71.1 & 36.2 \\ \hdashline
   Private & 81.4 & 72.3 & 80 & 27.68 & 19.67 & 26.52 & 40.7 \\ \hdashline
  \\
  \\
  %(further columns omitted)
  \end{tabular}
  \end{small}
  \caption{Summary statistics 2}
  \end{table*}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Your code does not contain `\begin{document}`, isen't minimal  and does not compile. Please use the edit button. A related question is here: [How to multicolumn in booktabs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75369/124842)

Comment: I would advice to *not* use the dashed lines. They are more confusing than helping.

Comment: Off-topic: The `article` document class doesn't recognize -- and hence ignores -- the option `10.5pt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

changes:

- introduced are three new packages: `malecell` (for two line headers), `multirow` for multi row cells and `siunitx` (for column type `S`)
- headers of group of columns are in `\multicolumn{3}{l}{...}`
- for intermediate header is used `\multicolumn{8}{l}{...}`
- in columns with number the column type is changed to `S`

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=0.5in,a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{caption}
    %    \usepackage{float}
    %    \usepackage{titlesec}
    %    \usepackage{capt-of}

     %dashed line
    \usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}
    \newcommand\mceight[1]{\multicolumn{8}{l}{#1}}
    \usepackage{arydshln}
    \setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
    \setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[ht] \centering
   \small
   \begin{tabular}{ l*{7}{S[table-format=2.2]} }
   \toprule
\multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Dependent\\ Variables}
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Share(\%)}}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Avg hourly wage}}
            & {\multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Avg\\ differential}}}              \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled}
    & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled}                       \\
   \hdashline                                                               \\
   \mceight{\textbf{PANEL A: 2011-2012}}                                    \\
   \midrule
   \\
   \mceight{Panel A.1: Sector (Urban or Rural)}                             \\ \hdashline
   Rural  & 51.5 & 54 & 52 & 28.54 & 18.83 & 26.92 & 51.5                   \\ \hdashline
   Urban  & 48.4 & 46 & 48 & 45.19 & 41.86 & 45    & 7.8                    \\ \hdashline                                                               \\
   \mceight{Panel A.2: Sector (Public or Private)}                          \\ \hdashline
   Public  & 18.6 & 27.7 & 20 & 75.55 & 55.44 & 71.1 & 36.2                 \\ \hdashline
   Private & 81.4 & 72.3 & 80 & 27.68 & 19.67 & 26.52 & 40.7                \\ \hdashline                                                               \\
   \mceight{Panel A.3: Education level}                                     \\ \hdashline
   Illilerate       & 11.7  & 27.7  & 14.3 & 21.11 & 13.92 & 18.87 & 51.6   \\ \hdashline
   primary          & 14.5  & 14.1  & 14.4 & 23.02 & 14.36 & 21.6  & 60.3   \\
   \hdashline
   secondary        & 46.1  & 26.08 & 42.9 & 30.13 & 20.29 & 29.17 & 48.49  \\
   \hdashline
   higher secondary & 12.12 & 11.1  & 11.9 & 43.13 & 39.6  & 42.6  & 8.9    \\
   \hdashline
   graduate         & 9.9   & 11.21 & 10.1 & 67.03 & 58.84 & 65.58 & 13.91  \\
   \hdashline
   post graduate    & 5.45 & 9.7   & 6.1   & 89.82 & 74.42 & 85.51 & 20.69  \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{small}
  \caption{Summary statistics 2}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

*note:*

- package `caption` contain `capt-of` features, so there is no need to load it
- reconsider, if all dashed lines are necessary (i would delete most of them)

---

**addendum:**
In case that you like to have table over more pages, the use of `longtable` is possible solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}
\newcommand\mceight[1]{\multicolumn{8}{l}{#1}}

\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]% text filler that table is two pages
   \begin{longtable}{ l*{7}{S[table-format=2.2]} }
\caption{Summary statistics 2}
\label{tab:...}                                                             \\
\toprule
\multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Dependent\\ Variables}}
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Share(\%)}}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Avg hourly wage}}
            & {\multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Avg\\ differential}}}              \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled}
    & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled}                       \\
   \hdashline                                                               \\
\endfirsthead
%%%%
\caption{Summary statistics 2 (cont.)}                                      \\
\toprule
\multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Dependent\\ Variables}}
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Share(\%)}}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Avg hourly wage}}
            & {\multirow[b]{2}{*}{\thead{Avg\\ differential}}}              \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled}
    & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled}                       \\
    \midrule                                                                \\
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
%%%%        
\mceight{\textbf{PANEL A: 2011-2012}}                                    \\
\midrule
\\
\mceight{Panel A.1: Sector (Urban or Rural)}                             \\ \hdashline
Rural  & 51.5 & 54 & 52 & 28.54 & 18.83 & 26.92 & 51.5                   \\ 
Urban  & 48.4 & 46 & 48 & 45.19 & 41.86 & 45    & 7.8                    \\ \\    \mceight{Panel A.2: Sector (Public or Private)}                          \\ \hdashline
Public  & 18.6 & 27.7 & 20 & 75.55 & 55.44 & 71.1 & 36.2                 \\ Private & 81.4 & 72.3 & 80 & 27.68 & 19.67 & 26.52 & 40.7                \\ \\    \mceight{Panel A.3: Education level}                                     \\ \hdashline
Illilerate       & 11.7  & 27.7  & 14.3 & 21.11 & 13.92 & 18.87 & 51.6   \\ primary          & 14.5  & 14.1  & 14.4 & 23.02 & 14.36 & 21.6  & 60.3   \\
secondary        & 46.1  & 26.08 & 42.9 & 30.13 & 20.29 & 29.17 & 48.49  \\
higher secondary & 12.12 & 11.1  & 11.9 & 43.13 & 39.6  & 42.6  & 8.9    \\
graduate         & 9.9   & 11.21 & 10.1 & 67.03 & 58.84 & 65.58 & 13.91  \\
post graduate    & 5.45 & 9.7   & 6.1   & 89.82 & 74.42 & 85.51 & 20.69  \\
\bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
For `longtable` solution now i stole some idea (regarding first and last columns header) from *Mico* answer ... and add `\midrule` for the `\endfoot`.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this works perfectly! Also, one more thing, is there a way I could break this table into multiple pages rather than compressing it in one single page?

Comment: yes, with use of `longtable`.

Comment: @KushaVerma, see addendum to my answer.

Comment: I'd get rid of the document class option `10.5pt`: It's not recognized (and hence is ignored) by the `article` document class. Also, are the cmidrules below the 1st and 8th columns needed/helpful?

Comment: @Mico, thanks for comment. i consider it in my answer edit [and mentioned, where i stole something :-)]. about font size you have right. now i removed option `10.5` points at `longtable` example. thank you!

Comment: @Zarko -- We are all proud followers here of Pablo Picasso, who supposedly said "Good artists borrow, great artists steal." :-)

Comment: @Zarko I tried following your answer, but the table seems to break down if I add more rows. I don't know if there is a way I can attach the image in the comments to illustrate.

Comment: please, edit your question and add image there. it should not be a problem to add as many as you wish new rows. however they should have the same number columns as have rows, which are in the my *mwe*.

Comment: @Zarko turns out I was just typing wrong, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which (a) uses a `longtable` environment instead of a nested `table`/`tabular` environment, (b) aligns the numbers in the numeric columns on their decimal markers and (c) provides a bit more structure to the first column.

Note that I've also dispensed with all `\hdashline` directives: they're simply not needed to communicate the *content* of the table to your readers. All the dashed lines do, then, is create visual clutter. Get rid of clutter. Your readers will appreciate it. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
    \usepackage{siunitx,ragged2e,longtable}

% Macro for typesetting multi-line header cells in bold
\newcommand{\boldblock}[1]{%
  \smash{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\bfseries\arraybackslash}c@{}}
  #1 
  \end{tabular}}}

% Set up a custom column type for the first column:
\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{Panel A.2: Sector (Public}
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}>{%
  \RaggedRight\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1}p{\mylength}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} L 
                      *{2}{S[table-format=2.1]}
                      S[table-format=2.0] 
                      *{3}{S[table-format=2.2]} 
                      S[table-format=2.1] @{}}
%% Headers and footers
   \caption{Summary statistics 2} \label{tab:sumstats}\\
   \toprule
   \textbf{Dependent Variables} & 
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Share (\%)}} &  
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Avg hourly wage}} &   
   \boldblock{Avg \\differential} \\ 
   \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
   & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled} 
   & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled} \\
   \midrule
   \addlinespace
   \endfirsthead

   \multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{Table \ref{tab:sumstats}, cont'd}
   \\ \addlinespace
   \toprule
   \textbf{Dependent Variables} & 
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Share (\%)}} &  
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Avg hourly wage}} &   
   \boldblock{Avg\\differential} \\ 
   \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
   & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled} 
   & \textbf{Men} & \textbf{Women} & \textbf{Pooled} \\
   \midrule
   \addlinespace
   \endhead

   \midrule
   \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(cont'd on following page)}\\
   \endfoot

   \bottomrule
   \endlastfoot

%% Body of longtable
   \textbf{PANEL A: 2011--2012} \\
   \addlinespace
   Panel A.1: Sector (Urban or Rural) \\ 
   Rural  & 51.5 & 54 & 52 & 28.54 & 18.83 & 26.92 & 51.5 \\ 
   Urban & 48.4 & 46 & 48 & 45.19 & 41.86 & 45 & 7.8 \\ 
   \addlinespace
   Panel A.2: Sector (Public or Private) \\ 
   Public & 18.6 & 27.7 & 20 & 75.55 & 55.44 & 71.1 & 36.2 \\ 
   Private & 81.4 & 72.3 & 80 & 27.68 & 19.67 & 26.52 & 40.7 \\ 
   \addlinespace
   Panel A.3: Education level \\
   Illiterate &&&&&&& 51.6\\
   \dots\\
   \dots\\
   %% remaining rows omitted

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```