# Longtable with repeating headers and horizontal rules

Tags: tables, longtable

I am trying to make a longtable, that has repeating headers. Also, each row has rules. In the second page, however, the rule repeats twice.It looks unpolished. How do I fix this?

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l} 
    \toprule
    Title \\ 
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \toprule
    Title \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \bottomrule

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

The Economist too uses rules

[image: Economist]

Comment: This is a known feature of `longtable` and has nothing to do with `array`, `booktabs` or `memoir`, so I deleted the tags

Comment: You should also ask yourself what exactly you're trying to achieve with all those `\hddashline` directives. The `longtable` will look a lot cleaner (or, to use your phrase, more polished) if all, or at least most, of these directives are simply omitted. Your readers will thank you.

Comment: Mico, The confusion comes from the MWE. My actual data is several columns wide. I have added a screen-shot. Do you still suggest that omitting rules will improve readability?

Comment: see answer for long table in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387308/using-multicolumn-with-booktabs/387317

Comment: @AK16 - Are you familiar with the Latin proverb, "Quod licet Iovis, non licet bovis"? Speaking for myself here, I doubt the table from *The Economist* magazine would be less legible had all dashed lines been omitted. :-)

Comment: I just found out "Gods may do what cattle may not". In the absence of information as to what constitutes good formatting, I went with the Economist.

Comment: @AK16 - About your real table (shown in a screenshot): I'd say the main problems with this table are (a) the header material isn't all that well organized and (b) there seems to be no grouping amongst the rows; if there is a natural grouping, it's not exactly easily visible in the table. While the dashed lines helps the reader's eyes move left and right in a given row, they do nothing in terms of providing structure to the contents of the table.

Comment: Mico, these are very valuable comments and I'm grateful for them. Please can you suggest how I may show grouping. Alternate bands of grey?

Comment: I honestly don't understand your table well enough to be confident about giving advice regarding how one might go about providing some  (visual) grouping. E.g., what's the the relationship between the entries in the first and second columns? Do rows 4&5, 6-9, and 13-17 belong together? The first three rows have no entries in the first column: what does that mean? Only you can answer these questions.

Answer (score 1):

I kinda stumbled on a solution. It may have drawbacks but it works for me.

Adding these 2 lines removed the problem

```
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
```

The MWE now becomes

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l} 
    \toprule
    Title \\ 
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \toprule
    Title \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \bottomrule

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Page 2 output is shown:

[image: Output]

Comment: at me it works fine without `\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt} \setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}`. probably you have installed outdated  packages. upgrade it! and not forget, that `longtable` need to be compiled at least twice that it gain final format.

Comment: \endhead solved the issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), there are no repeating horizontal dash lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\NewTableCommand{\hdashline}{\hline[0.3pt,dashed]}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
]{colspec={X},rowhead=1} 
    \toprule
    Title \\
    \midrule
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \hdashline
    D \\ \hdashline
    A \\ \hdashline
    B \\ \hdashline
    C \\ \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]