# How to draw table like this in latex

Tags: tables, texstudio

[image]

Hello, I am trying to draw a table in the texstudio. Since, I am new can anybody help , how to do that ?

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far? Make your question clearer: Should the part DE - AE in a new table nested in the bigger table or not?

Comment: You could start by taking a look at the `booktabs` package.

Comment: Two usefull tips for drawing tabulars: in TeXstudio go to Wizards > Quick Tabular
or go to http://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: @Joule everything should be like as i described in the diagram. Three coloums and 2 rows. in the last coloum, it should split the coloum into two parts

Comment: Install Excel to Latex addin. Format the table in excel and generate codes for latex through this add in. The addin is available [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex?lang=en)

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387308/using-multicolumn-with-booktabs?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make nested tables in the third column. It can be simplified a bit with some macro:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\def\xxx#1#2{\begin{tabular}{|p{4em}|p{4em}|}\hline#1&#2\\\hline\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    foo & bah & Variability Process \\
    11 & 12 & \xxx{13}{14}\\\hline
    21 & 22 & \xxx{23}{24}\\\hline
    31 & 32 & \xxx{33}{34}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Said that, consider avoid vertical rules and use the `booktabs` rules:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\def\xxx#1#2{\begin{tabular}{|p{4em}|p{4em}|}\hline#1&#2\\\hline\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llll}\toprule
    foo & bah & Variability Process \\\midrule
    11 & 12 & \xxx{13}{14}\\
    21 & 22 & \xxx{23}{24}\\
    31 & 32 & \xxx{33}{34}\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe2]

or better:

[image: mwe3]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\def\xxx#1#2{{\tabcolsep1pt\begin{tabular}{p{4em}cp{4em}}\cellcolor{gray!20}#1&&\cellcolor{gray!20}#2\\\end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}
\extrarowheight2pt
\begin{tabular}{llll}\toprule
    foo & bah & Variability Process \\\midrule
    11 & 12 & \xxx{13}{14}\\
    21 & 22 & \xxx{23}{24}\\
    31 & 32 & \xxx{33}{34}\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```